# Oracle db won't update through webapi, but db will update through unittest

Tags: asp.net-web-api, oracle11g, odp.net

I'm having a problem with my asp.net webapi project.
I'm using ODP.NET for connecting with an Oracle Database.
My webapi is build up out of 3 layers (service, core, dal).

My problem is that my database won't update when i'm trying to change/create/delete an object, but the DBContext in the ef will.
So when i'm calling my api through "api/user/1" with a put request the ef updates the object, but doesn't commit it to the database.

The weird part is, when i'm trying to update an object through unittesting the database will update. But then i'm calling the controller directly: UserController.Put(id, object).

Does someone knows how this is possible and how I can solve this?

EDIT: CODE

*UnitTest:*

```cs
var _controller = new UserController();

var user = new User()
{
    Name = "userTest"
};

//Adding user through web -- Doesn't add to database
var _client = new RestClient("http://localhost");

RestRequest request = new RestRequest("api/User", Method.POST);
request.AddParameter("text/json", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user), ParameterType.RequestBody);

IRestResponse response = _client.Execute(request);

//Adding user through controller -- Does add to database
_controller.Post(user);

var userData = (List<User>)_controller.Get();
Assert.IsNotNull(userData.Find(u => u.Naam == user.Naam));
```

*UserController:*

```cs
// POST api/User
public void Post([FromBody]T value)
{
    _service.Create(value);
}
```

*UserService:*

```cs
public void Create(User value)
{
    var _repository = new UserRepository();
    var _mapper = new UserMapper();
    var newUser = _mapper.Map(value);

    _repository.Add(newUser);
    _repository.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Could you paste some code here?

Comment: Did you get any exception on Web API ?

Comment: No I didn't, but I already have an answer. I just can't post the answer because of the safetycheck of SO. I need to wait for 8 hours before I can answer my own question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you use dependency injection? If so, try to find if there is a difference.

Comment: Good work Jack ;)

This was indeed the problem. I fixed it by filling the routing table of the UnityControlFactory in every controller. So now with every call the dependencies are reset.

Comment: I've changed my Dependency Injector to Autofac instead of Unity. Autofac works better!